# Мне надо разукрасить цвет клеточки как на шахматной доске

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня есть код Python который создает окно 600 на 600 пикселей, в котором есть 64 квадрата(8х8), и мне надо сделать чтобы эта "доска" была разукрашена так как шахматная.

Вот то что у меня есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот что надо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот сам код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Шашки')



square_color = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b',
                'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a',
                'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b',
                'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a',
                'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b',
                'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a',
                'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b',
                'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a',]

canvas = Canvas(root, width=700, height=700, bg='#fff')
canvas.pack()




def square():
    global square_color
    y = 0
    while y < 700:
        x = 0
        while x < 700:
            canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+88, y+88, fill='#fff', 
    outline='#000')
            x = x + 88
            y = y + 88

square()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def board():
    fill = '#fff'
    outline = '#000'
    size = 88

    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = i * size, j * size, i * size + size, j * size + size

            canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=fill, outline=outline)
            fill, outline = outline, fill

        fill, outline = outline, fill
```

88 можете заменить в зависимости от ширины доски... или передавать параметром вообще в функцию... или вычислять прямо в функции - зависит от ваших потребностей. но это я думаю вы сами сможете сделать.
и еще не понятно зачем вам нужен массив square_color...

Comment: Спасибо, все работает)